# I don't understand this particular line

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a programming course at school, in Python 3. And the task is basically to make a program that asks for two integers between 1-9. The outcome will be a multiplication table with the amount of rows of the first integer and the number of columns of the second integer. So If one would type in 5 and 6 they would get:

[image]

I found a code here on SO that generates that program. And right now. I am trying to dissect it and understand it. But I am stuck on some points.

so here is the code:

```
row,col=5,6
i=0
while i <= row :
    j=0
    while j <= col:
        if i+j==0 : print('{:4s}'.format(''),end='') #corner
        elif i*j==0 : print('{:4d}'.format(i+j),end='') # border
        else : print('{:4d}'.format(i*j),end='') # table
        j=j+1   
    print()
    i=i+1
```

Ok. So what my tiny brain doesn't understand is how the border on the left hand side, which is vertical, is generated. If the first condition is met, a blank space in the upper left corner will be generated, and +1 will be added to the variable j. Afterwards, condition two will be met which will in turn give a horizontal border, this will continue until j is greater than col. But if j>col, how can the left border be generated? What part of the code generates the vertical border?

Also. What do the input in the curly braces mean before the .format operator? for instance, how does `{:4s}` differ from `{4:d}`? Are they simply distances and "s" is for strings and d for numbers?

Also, what does the last, statement `print()` do?

Comment: Read the *alignment* and *padding* sections on https://pyformat.info/

Comment: You seem to lacka basic understanding of `str.format`. I suggest you take the time to read the documentation or a site like pyformat.info , as suggested by wim, and try to run some example in the interactive interpreter. If after understanding that function you still don't understand that code you should try to ask a specific question about what puzzles you. This will take less time, and you'll learn much more than asking here.

Comment: I think you may be missing that it is printing just one line, at a time. As for the syntax details, you should refer to the documentation, or your textbook.

Comment: Last tip: you do **not** learn how to program by copy&pasting other people code and asking on SO. You learn to program by reading documentation & tutorials *and spend effort writing your own code*. Trust me: it's faster and way more effective.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks guys.

Comment: My suggestion would be to comment out the first two clauses of the `if`/`elif`/`else` and just uncoditionally do `print('{:4d}'.format(i*j),end='')`. Once you understand what that does, you can look at the other lines to see how they change its behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The output of this program is:

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6
   1   1   2   3   4   5   6
   2   2   4   6   8  10  12
   3   3   6   9  12  15  18
   4   4   8  12  16  20  24
   5   5  10  15  20  25  30
```

Let us look at each if/elif/else step:

```
    if i+j==0 : print('{:4s}'.format(''),end='') #corner
```

Since i and j are always non-negative, this case of `i+j==0` will happen only when both i and j are 0. In this case, we print a blank string padded to be 4 characters long - this creates the empty corner at the top left, which is at 0,0 in the grid. Also note that `end=''` ensures that print won't go to the next line automatically (which is the default behavior). Note that the `print()` call at the bottom of the row loop will take you to the next line.

```
    elif i*j==0 : print('{:4d}'.format(i+j),end='') # border
```

if both i and j are not 0, (which is why we use elif), the only way we get this case is when one of them is 0. In this case, `i+j` is equal to the nonzero value between i and j. We are printing the character i at the beginning of each row, and the corresponding non-zero character j along the top row, at the top of each column. See also that each number is formatted to be 4 characters wide (with the 4d).

```
    else : print('{:4d}'.format(i*j),end='') # table
```

If both i and j are not zero, we will come to this else case. We simply print the product of i and j, at each location within the table.

You can look at the [format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatspec) for full details, but in this case, `s` stands for string and `d` stands for numbers, and the number (like 4d) requires the output to have 4 characters. The curly braces specify where we position each of the values passed to the format method (in case you have multiple of them, you can have multiple pairs of curly braces).